# Issue with StorageAccessFramework and DownloadManager

Tags: android, uri, saf

I have one problem. I am developing some Streaming/Video downloading app. 
I am using [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html) for video downloads.

Request is to offer user's to pick destination for saving (SDCard or internal phone storage).

I have problems on Lollipop with [SAF](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) and DownloadManager.

I am offering to the user to pick directory for storing files I download:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FOR_DESTINATION);
```

and in onActivityResult i am getting it via

```
Uri treeUri = data.getData();
DocumentFile destinationDirUri = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
```

Now, I need to set this destination as destination to DownloadManager.Request

```
Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(getDownloadUrl()));
request.setTitle(downloadInfo.getTitle());
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setDestinationUri(destinationDirUri);
```

After I select "Downloads/video" directory, and perform

```
DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

I am getting

```
E/RecordDownloader﹕ Error while retrieving download infos    
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file URI: content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3ADownload%2Fvideo
W/System.err﹕ at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
W/System.err﹕ at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:475)
W/System.err﹕ at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1207)
W/System.err﹕ at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:946)
W/System.err﹕ at ch.teleboy.download.RecordDownloader.enqueueDownloadRequest(RecordDownloader.java:102)
W/System.err﹕ at ch.teleboy.download.RecordDownloader.access$300(RecordDownloader.java:48)
W/System.err﹕ at ch.teleboy.download.RecordDownloader$DownloaderTask.run(RecordDownloader.java:191)
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

If I try to write some file to selected location, it works.

```
DocumentFile newFile = destinationDirUri.createFile("text/plain", "test.txt");
OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newFile.getUri());
out.write("Some dummy text...".getBytes());
out.close()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could solve the problem? If yes, please describe the solution.

Comment: No I did not. We postponed feature for happier time :)

Comment: Are u saving the treeURI from activity on result? Coz I think its already parsed and u are trying to parse it again, and it might cause problems, its just a guess...

Comment: It was long time ago, but I think that was the case. It makes sense.

If I get some time I will find that branch and try. Maybe we can help to some one else. Thank you.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?

Comment: Did you ever solve the problem? do you maybe need to create the empty file and then pass the file uri to the download manager?